# Custom Walker menu depth opening problem

Tags: walker, sub-menu

I'v create custom categories walker menu:

```
   <?php
    /**
     * Show Categories menu
     *
     */
    $seller_id = (int) get_query_var('author');
    ?>
    <aside class="cat-menu">
        <h3 class="cat-menu-title"><?php echo "Catégories"; ?></h3>
        <div id="cat-drop-stack">
        <?php

        global $wpdb;

        $sql = "SELECT t.term_id,t.name, tt.parent FROM $wpdb->terms as t
                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tt on t.term_id = tt.term_id
                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr on tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p on tr.object_id = p.ID
                    WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
                    AND p.post_type = 'product'
                    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                    AND p.post_author = $seller_id GROUP BY t.term_id";

        $categories = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
        //var_dump($categories);

        $walker = new Dokan_Store_Category_Walker( $seller_id );
        echo "<ul style=\"width:250px;height:400px;overflow: scroll;\">";
        echo call_user_func_array( array(&$walker, 'walk'), array($categories, 0, array()) );
        echo "</ul>";
        ?>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <script>
        ( function ( $ ) {
            $( '#cat-drop-stack li.has-children' ).on( 'click', '> a span.caret-icon', function ( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var self = $( this ),
                    liHasChildren = self.closest( 'li.has-children' );

                if ( !liHasChildren.find( '> ul.children' ).is( ':visible' ) ) {
                    self.find( 'i.fa' ).addClass( 'fa-rotate-90' );
                    if ( liHasChildren.find( '> ul.children' ).hasClass( 'level-0' ) ) {
                        self.closest( 'a' ).css( { 'borderBottom': 'none' } );
                    }
                }

                liHasChildren.find( '> ul.children' ).slideToggle( 'fast', function () {
                    if ( !$( this ).is( ':visible' ) ) {
                        self.find( 'i.fa' ).removeClass( 'fa-rotate-90' );

                        if ( liHasChildren.find( '> ul.children' ).hasClass( 'level-0' ) ) {
                            self.closest( 'a' ).css( { 'borderBottom': '1px solid #eee' } );
                        }
                    }
                } );
            } );
        } )( jQuery );
    </script>
    <?php
```

and the class:

```
class Dokan_Store_Category_Walker extends Dokan_Category_Walker {

    function __construct( $seller_id ) {
        $this->store_url = dokan_get_store_url ( $seller_id );
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        extract( $args );
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );

        $url = $this->store_url . 'section/' . $category->term_id;
        $selected_cat = get_query_var( 'term' );
        $a_selected_class = $selected_cat == $category->term_id ? 'class="selected"' : '';

        if ( $depth == 0 ) {
            $caret = $args['has_children'] ? ' <span class="caret-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>' : '';
            $class_name = $args['has_children'] ? ' class="has-children parent-cat-wrap"' : ' class="parent-cat-wrap"';
            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $class_name . '>' . "\n\t" .'<a href="' . $url . '"'. $a_selected_class .'>' . $category->name . $caret . '</a>' . "\n";
        } else {
            $caret = $args['has_children'] ? ' <span class="caret-icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>' : '';
            $class_name = $args['has_children'] ? ' class="has-children"' : '';
            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $class_name . '><a href="' . $url . '"'.$a_selected_class.'>' . $category->name . $caret . '</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Actually all depth are opened, e.g.:

> ```
> cat01
>  cat01_1
>   cat01_1_1
>  cat01_2
> cat02
>  cat02_1
> ```

I need menu like this (not all the sub cat opened):

> ```
> cat01
>  cat01_1
>  cat01_2
> cat02
>  cat02_1
> ```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `echo call_user_func_array( array(&$walker, 'walk'), array($categories, 2, array()) );`

Comment: Hey Sally, thank you so much !!! :-) finaly works fine, why this is not documented anywhere ? searched few days... google not my friend for this :-))

Comment: What I suggested is to change the `depth` arg (which you previously set it to `0`); and `depth` is actually well-documented in the default 'walker' `class`: [`Walker_Category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_category/#source) (see line #89 of the source/code), which I believe is the `class` that's being extended by the `Dokan_Category_Walker` `class`.

Comment: Thanks sally, but after some test when I use deph 2 if I try to click to open subcat (deph 3) this not work, subcat are not avaible. I need all cat and subcat, this why I used 0 for deph but I need too close all deph by default because I have lot off cat...

Comment: I Try to find how to collapse all cat by default in other word

Comment: Try the script in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I Try to find how to collapse all cat by default in other word

In that case, then try this script (replace the one you have now):

```
<script>
    ( function ( $ ) {
        $( 'li.has-children', '#cat-drop-stack' ).on( 'click', '> a span.caret-icon', function ( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var self = $( this ),
                submenu = self.closest( 'li.has-children' ).find( '> ul.children' );

            if ( !submenu.is( ':visible' ) ) {
                self.find( 'i.fa' ).addClass( 'fa-rotate-90' );
                if ( submenu.hasClass( 'level-0' ) ) {
                    self.closest( 'a' ).css( { 'borderBottom': 'none' } );
                }
            }

            submenu.slideToggle( 'fast', function () {
                if ( !$( this ).is( ':visible' ) ) {
                    self.find( 'i.fa' ).removeClass( 'fa-rotate-90' );

                    if ( submenu.hasClass( 'level-0' ) ) {
                        self.closest( 'a' ).css( { 'borderBottom': '1px solid #eee' } );
                    }
                }
            } );
        } )
        .find( '> ul.children' ).hide().end()
        .filter( '.level-0' ).find( '> a span.caret-icon' ).click();
    } )( jQuery );
</script>
```

[Demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVvWqW)

Comment: Perfect Sally !! sorry did say "Collapse" first in my post and no depth :-(

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. =)